# Kafka 0.8.2 throws java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, disconnect, apache-kafka

I get this error quite a lot:

```
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
```

And this is followed by:

```
kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread:Shutting down
```

Any lights on this would be helpful!!!

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue or is it intermittent? Can you share the code you are using from which the exception emanates?

Comment: Intermittent. Its not in my code. I start a Consumer and fetch data.

Comment: At some point, the consumer disconnects with this messge. Not in the context of my code